# Simple way to plot netCDF variables on Mollweide projection in R

Tags: coordinate-system, r, netcdf

Is there a very simple way to plot up variables from a netCDF file that are stored in a regular lat-lon grid (-90to90˚N, 0-360˚E) onto the now more popular Mollweide projection?

For example say I have something like the following:

```
lon <- seq(-90,90,2.5) # really these data would come from the netCDF file...
lat <- seq(0,356.25,3.75)
myvar <- runif(length(lon)*length(lat))
mymat <- array(dim=c(length(lon), length(lat)), myvar)
```

Which I can plot up easily with something like image:

```
image(lon, lat, myvar)
```

But what I'd like to do is convert the myvar array and reproject it so that I can plot it in the Mollweide projection:

```
... convert to Mollweide projection ...
image(myvar_converted)
```

I'm looking for a very generic approach and ideally something that would allow me to add on points, lines etc on to the plots using base functions if possible.

Comment: You should start giving a look to the following R packages: raster, rgdal and maps. Then you'll realize that, thanks to Google, there are many tutorials available, like this: http://blog.fellstat.com/?p=130

Comment: Take a look at the `gdalUtils` package, specifically gdalwarp. You'll need to write your source data out first though.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just post a few pointers here for now: when I get a chance, I'll try to make this a more comprehensive and easily-consumable answer. But for now:

First off, consider changing your title better match (IIUC--ICBW) the terms folks in this domain use for this sort of usecase, and therefore to make it more findable. What you want to do is more usually called *projecting* spatial data from unprojected/lon-lat (aka "global") to Mollweide (or other desired output [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection)). (This may also be called "reprojecting" or "regridding," but "projecting" is more correct for this usecase.)

I have code (which needs refactoring, but works and is IMHO rather better documented than a lot of science code on the web) that does something similar to what you want (along with lots of other things that you don't want): projecting [netCDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetCDF) from global lon-lat to a different projection (in my case, LCC), e.g.:

- [CLM_CN_global_to_AQMEII-NA](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/clm_cn_global_to_aqmeii-na)
- [GFED-3.1_global_to_AQMEII-NA](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/gfed-3.1_global_to_aqmeii-na)
- [GEIA_regrid](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/geia_regrid)

Of these, `GEIA_regrid` is the oldest, and probably least well-written, but it does use (IIRC) R package=`image`, which you seem to want. My recommendations:

1. Read up on the different [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) plot packages. My experience was, I started with `image` but rapidly found I needed `lattice` functionality, and eventually realized that I should have started by learning `ggplot2`. There now may be an even newer/better R package for spatial plotting. (If your project is *truly* a one-off this won't matter.)
2. Read the `README`s for either [GFED-3.1_global_to_AQMEII-NA](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/gfed-3.1_global_to_aqmeii-na) (which IIRC is a bit newer/cleaner, but a bit more complex due to the way GFED provides its data) or [CLM_CN_global_to_AQMEII-NA](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/clm_cn_global_to_aqmeii-na) to (hopefully :-) get some idea how these codes/projects work. To a first approximation, these projects

   1. use [bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) to drive [NCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NCAR_Command_Language) and [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) code. (If you're gonna be working with netCDF much, consider learning a bit about NCL: it's "the bomb" for netCDF hacking.) If I was starting over, I might try an all-python solution, since the python netCDF libraries are pretty good.
   2. have an `uber_driver.sh` which sets up the environment and filespace (either from local filetree or from git repo) and then calls a "project driver" (e.g., [CLMCN_driver.sh](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/clm_cn_global_to_aqmeii-na/src/HEAD/CLMCN_driver.sh?at=master), [GFED_driver.sh](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/gfed-3.1_global_to_aqmeii-na/src/HEAD/GFED_driver.sh?at=master)), which calls the NCL and R work scripts.
3. The work scripts that most do what you want are the `*regrid*` ones: [regrid_global_to_AQMEII.r](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/clm_cn_global_to_aqmeii-na/src/HEAD/regrid_global_to_AQMEII.r?at=master), [vis_regrid_vis.r](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/gfed-3.1_global_to_aqmeii-na/src/HEAD/vis_regrid_vis.r?at=master). You'll probably need to make a buncha changes to make these do what you want, but you will *definitely* need to change one thing: output-projection specification in variable name=`out.proj4`. This is a [PROJ.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PROJ.4) string, which is "the standard way" to really, *really* specify geographic projections, or lack thereof (in the lon-lat case).

   - I was required to work with a rather "fiddly" output format, so I set `out.proj4` *programmatically* using a library that deeply understands my output format.
   - You will probably want to explicitly set your `out.proj4` for Mollweide as indicated [here](http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/proj_list/mollweide.html), but (as indicated there) you will need to know the appropriate [false easting, false northing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easting_and_northing), and [central meridian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Notable_lines) for your output in order to set that.